# Using -> on a static object

Tags: php, class, oop, methods, static

While reading this: http://propelorm.org/ I noticed that they are using -> sign on a static object and using several different methods of it as a "one-liner".

Or does the static object return an instance which from the methods are being called from?

What ever is the case I would like to read more about this. What is this called and does it really work with static objects?

Comment: How do you mean _static objects_? `className::func()->variable;`? There `className::func()` just returns a very normal object… nothing special static?

Comment: The static method is returning an object on which they are calling the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that they are using -> sign on a static object

By static object you mean to say static method and that the code you are referring to is this:

```
classBookQuery::create()->findPK(123);
```

They are not using `->` on a static method. They are using `->` on the *object returned by the static method.*

You can try it yourself:

```
class AClass
{
    public static function aMethod()
    {
        return new BClass();
    }
}

class BClass
{
    public function bMethod($int)
    {
        echo $int;
    }
}

AClass::aMethod()->bMethod(123); // output: 123
```

Comment: Ah, figured. What is this called? EDIT: Now I think I got it. Each of the methods return a new object so the -> chain never breaks?

Comment: @unska Look up the "factory design pattern"

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in the comments, the static function `BookQuery::create()` just returns another object.

The "arrow" operates on the returned object.

Example:

```
class Car {
  public function beep() {
    echo 'BEEP';
  }
}

class CarProvider {
  public static function get() {
    return new Car();
  }
}

// outputs 'BEEP';
CarProvider::get()->beep();

// the same as this
$car = CarProvider::get();
$car->beep();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is oftentimes know as method chaining.  The static method call is returning an instantiated object against which another method is called.  This sort of construct is often achieve like this:

```
class myobject_factory {
    public static function get_object () {
        return new myobject;
    }
}

class myobject {
    protected $some_property;
    public function set_some_property($value) {
        $this->some_property = $value;
        return $this;
    }
    public function get_some_propert() {
        return $this->some_property;
    }
}

$property = myobject_factory::get_object()->set_some_property('foobar')->get_some_property();
```

This is obviously a trivial example, but you can see how chaining is enabled because the setter on myobject returns `$this`.